# fill a matrix with weibull probabilities

Tags: r, function, matrix, distribution, weibull

I'm having trouble using R to fill a matrix with rows of Weibull probabilities with a different 'scale factor' on each row. At th moment each colum is filled identically.

I've tried a number of methods, but below I show what I've done. I think there's something fundamental I'm missing!

to get list of 26 Scale factors:

```
Shape <- 2
x <- seq(0,25,1)

Scale <- NULL
for (i in 1:26){
Scale[i] <- x[i]/(gamma(1+1/Shape))
}
```

prepare matrix:

```
size <- length(x)                   ## size of matrix
w.dist <- matrix(
    rep(x,size),
    nrow= size,
    ncol= size,
    byrow= T)
```

apply Weibull function on each line of the matrix (for each x value (wind speed))

```
for (i in 1:26){ 
w.dist[i,] <- apply(w.dist,2,function(x)dweibull(x,Shape,Scale[i]))
}
```

OR:

```
w.dist <- matrix(dweibull(x, shape=Shape, scale=Scale), nrow=26, ncol=26, byrow=TRUE)
```

I can't get either method to work. Any help would be extremely helpful!

Comment: What if you replaced the line in for loop with `w.dist[i, ] <- dweibull(w.dist[i, ], Shape, Scale[i])`?

Comment: You cannot get values with scale = 0. And with the values stored in "w.dist", you will get very small values.

Comment: As an aside, you have `Scale[1]=0`. A Weibull distribution with  `scale=0` produces `NaN`s

Comment: @RHertel Just what I said.

Comment: I was typing my comment while yours wasn't posted yet. You were faster.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the apply?

Comment: Since you use a loop anyway, @RomanLuštrik's answer seems to be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

In the loop

```
for (i in 1:26){ w.dist[i,] <- apply(w.dist,2,function(x)dweibull(x,Shape,Scale[i])) }
```

the 'dweibull'-function is not applied to the wind speed values 'x', but to 'w.dist' containing undefined values. I tried the following:

```
windSpeed <- x
for (i in 1:26){ w.dist[i,] <- dweibull(windSpeed,Shape,Scale[i]) }
```

Then the rows of 'w.dist' contain reasonable values, e.g.

```
> w.dist[12,]
 [1] 0.000000000 0.012897797 0.025298144 0.036735430 0.046804881 0.055186204
 [7] 0.061659957 0.066115538 0.068550573 0.069062342 0.067832616 0.065107812
[13] 0.061176637 0.056347379 0.050926813 0.045202234 0.039427649 0.033814593
[19] 0.028527530 0.023683384 0.019354446 0.015573732 0.012341866 0.009634581
[25] 0.007410118 0.005615971
> sum(w.dist[12,])
[1] 0.9842882
```